# Headphones and earbuds not working properly on new HTC M10

Tags: htc, headphone-jack

I used an HTC M7 since it was released, never an issue of this kind.

Get the M10, which is overall great. It updated a few days ago to new firmware. But the following issues stand out:

- Bose [SoundTrue headphones](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00IUICOR6): Only work if I plug them in part way (all but the last 1 mm). If I plug them in all the way, I hear nothing.
- Skullcandy earbuds: Often have to re insert jack 1 or 2 times to get the mic to work.

Great phone.... but how to solve?

Comment: Same issue with Skullcandy Ink'd wired headphones on an HTC 10. They'll randomly phase out, and removing/reinserting them often doesn't work the first couple tries.